# How to insert data with entiity Framework core when the id is autogenerated?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to insert one row in 2 table of my database. The relation between those 2 tables is one to many. this is their **model**:

```
public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        TaskOwner = new HashSet<TaskOwner>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public int ActualEffort { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignationDate { get; set; }
    public int EstEffort { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstEnd { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TaskOwner> TaskOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public partial class TaskOwner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employe Employe { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the **context**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ProjectId)
                .HasName("FKTask25514");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Action)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("action")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

            entity.Property(e => e.ActualEffort)
                .HasColumnName("actual_effort")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.AssignationDate).HasColumnName("assignation_date");

            entity.Property(e => e.EstEffort)
                .HasColumnName("est_effort")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.EstEnd).HasColumnName("est_end");

            entity.Property(e => e.IsComplete).HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");

            entity.Property(e => e.ProjectId)
                .HasColumnName("project_id")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("status")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                .WithMany(p => p.Task)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FKTask25514");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskOwner>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Task_Owner");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.EmployeId)
                .HasName("FKTask_Owner320287");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TaskId)
                .HasName("FKTask_Owner395416");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.EmployeId)
                .HasColumnName("employe_id")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaskId)
                .HasColumnName("task_id")
                .HasColumnType("int(10)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Employe)
                .WithMany(p => p.TaskOwner)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FKTask_Owner320287");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Task)
                .WithMany(p => p.TaskOwner)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FKTask_Owner395416");
        });
```

One Task can be owned by multiple TaskOwner. I tried this approch :

```
Models.Task task = new Models.Task()
                    {
                        Status = tde.Status.ToString(),
                        Action = tde.Subject.ToString(),
                        IsComplete = tde.IsComplete,
                        EstEnd = tde.DueDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now),
                        AssignationDate = tde.DateTimeCreated.Date,
                        ActualEffort = Convert.ToInt32(tde.ActualWork),
                        EstEffort = Convert.ToInt32(tde.TotalWork),
                        ProjectId = (from p in _context.Project
                                     where p.ProjectSapId == Convert.ToInt32(tde.BillingInformation)
                                     select p.Id).First(),
                    };

                    Models.TaskOwner taskOwner = new Models.TaskOwner()
                    {
                        EmployeId = employee.Id,
                    };
                    task.TaskOwner.Add(taskOwner);
                    _context.Task.Add(task);
```

And then save it into the database but I always revieve this error:

> self referencing loop detected with type 'Models.TaskOwner' . Path '[6].taskOwner[0].employe.taskOwner'.

If I could, I would just use the id of the task I've just created and link it to the taskOwner model but since the id is autogenerated I can't or at least I dont know how. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way of doing what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a `Task` has zero or more `TaskOwners`. Every `TaskOwner` has exactly one `Task`. There are no `TaskOwners` without a `Task`.

This means, that if you have an existing `TaskOwner` in the database, you can't have it own a second `Task`. However you can let it own a different `Task` instead of the one it owns now.

If you introduce (add) an object to the database that has a relation ship to an existing object in the database, you can either use the Id of the related object or the object itself (which of course has a non-zero Id).

If the related object is also new, just assign the related object to the object you will Add. you won't have to Add the related object separately.

Note that as long as you haven't used SaveChanges you can't use the Id of any new object.

**Introduce a TaskOwner which owns an existing Task and existing Employee**

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    int employeeId = FetchEmployeeId(...);
    int taskId = FetchTaskId(...);

    TaskOwner introducedTaskOwner = dbContext.TaskOwners.Add(new TaskOwner()
    {
        // don't fill the ID!
        EmployeeId = employeeId,
        TaskId = taskId,

        ... // other properties
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // now the introduced task owner has an Id!
    return introducedTaskOwner;
}
```

**Introduce a TaskOwner together with a new Task. Use existing Employee**

Now you can't fill the TaskId, instead fill a Task:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    int employeeId = FetchEmployeeId(...);

    TaskOwner introducedTaskOwner = dbContext.TaskOwners.Add(new TaskOwner()
    {
        // don't fill the TaskOwner ID!
        EmployeeId = employeeId,

        // Give the Task owner a non-existing Task:
        Task = new Task()
        {
            // don't fill the Task ID!
            // don't fill the collection of TaskOwners

            ... // fill other Task properties
        }

        ... // other task owner properties
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // now both the task owner and the task are introduced. Both have an ID
    Debug.Assert(introducedTaskOwner.Id != 0);
    Debug.Assert(intrducedTaskOwner.TaskId != 0);
    Debug.Assert(introducedTaskOwner.Task.Id != 0);
}
```

If you want you could first introduce the Task and then the TaskOwner. As long as you haven't used SaveChanges you can't use any Id.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    int employeeId = FetchEmployeeId(...);

    Task introducedTask = dbContext.Tasks.Add(new Task()
    {
        // don't fill the Task ID!
        TaskOwners = new List<TaskOwner>(); // This Task has no owners yet

            ... // fill other Task properties
    });

    TaskOwner introducedTaskOwner = dbContext.TaskOwners.Add(new TaskOwner()
    {
        // don't fill the TaskOwner ID!
        EmployeeId = employeeId,

        // Give the Task owner a the introduced task
        Task = introducedTask,

        ... // other task owner properties
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

You could also do it the other way round: you could add a TaskOwner to an existing (or newly added) Task

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    int employeeId = FetchEmployeeId(...);

    // get existing task:
    Task existingTask = dbContext.Tasks
        .Where(task => task.ActualEffort > ...)
        .OrderBy(task => task.ActualEffort)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // add an owner to the task owners collection:
    existingTask.TaskOwners.Add(new TaskOwner()
    {
        // don't fill the TaskOwner ID!
        EmployeeId = employeeId,
        // no need to fill the TaskId, nor the Task
        // Entity Framework knows the Task to which it belongs, because you 
        // add it to the TaskOwners collection
        ...           
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Conclusion: as long as you don't have an Id, use the complete object. If the object is not added yet, entity framework will add it

Comment: Thank you very much! With your answer I have realize that I made a mistake in the strucutre of my BD. It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the `Models.Task` and access Auto-generated ID and then Save `TaskOwner` model.

Comment: Isn't there a better way where I don't need to save twice in the database for every task i'll add in one call? I've read that save is a very expensive call.

Comment: @MarcelJr.SamsonMorasse something came up so couldn't give you proper answer. Good that you found a solution. Cheers.